# message.mentions.users.first() not defined - discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

`const user = message.mentions.users.first();`
`console.log(user)`

This is just a snippet of code, but the console outputs undefined. Above this is boilerplate command handler stuff. Other things work fine, but the message.mentions.users.first is the problem.  I've tried almost everything from other questions like this. Any ideas?

Comment: How did you mention someone on Discord?

Comment: ^giverole @Person argument2

Comment: Do mentions and users have some content? Can you log those to see what comes out?

Comment: message.mentions.users returns Collection(0) [Map] {} however, message.mentions returns ```MessageMentions {
  everyone: false,
  users: Collection(0) [Map] {},
  roles: Collection(1) [Map] {
    '826814970942586951' => Role {
      guild: [Guild],
      id: '826814970942586951',
      name: 'Reginald',
      color: 0,
      hoist: false,
      rawPosition: 3,
      permissions: [Permissions],
      managed: true,
      mentionable: false,
      deleted: false
    }
  },
  _members: null,
  _channels: null,
  crosspostedChannels: Collection(0) [Map] {}
}```

Comment: The person I'm mentioning is Reginald. It says "mentionable: false" what does that mean?

Comment: Problem solved! Apparently the "Reginald" person was unable to be mentioned. I tried with someone else and it worked! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Reginald is the `role` not a `user` that's why message.mentions gives you 'mentionable:false'
check if there is role same name as 'Reginald'